# vectorizing a point to line/segment/ray distance function (matlab)

Tags: matlab, line, vectorization, point, raytracing

I am using the function from [here](https://monkeyproofsolutions.nl/how-to-calculate-the-shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line/) in order to calculate the distances of multiple rays to multiple points in the space. The way I am doing it now is by forming two `for` loops as you can notice in the code below since the `distancePoint2Line()` function is not vectorized. However, when I have to through an amount of rays around 2000-3000 rays and find their distance in an amount of 6000-7000 points in the space this takes a lot of time. Therefore, I would like if possible to vectorize the `distancePoint2Line()` in order to optimize the processing time.

The input to the existing `distancePoint2Line()` function is the starting point, the end point of the line, segment or ray, an independent point in the space and the type of line and is briefly given as:

```
function [d, C, t0] = distancePoint2Line(A, B, P, varargin)
% - lineType definition
if (nargin < 4)
    lineType = 'line';
lineType = 'line';
else
    lineType = varargin{1};
end
%% Algorithm

% Direction vector 
% M = B - A;
M = B;

% Running parameter t0 defines the intersection point of line through A and B
% and the perpendicular through P
t0  = dot(M, P - A) / dot(M, M);

% Intersection point of the perpendicular and line through A and B
intersectPnt = A + t0 * M;

switch lower(lineType)
    case 'line'
        % Line: intersection point is always closest.
        C   = intersectPnt;

    case 'segment'
        % Line segment
        if t0 < 0
            % Start point is closest.
            C   = A;
        elseif t0 > 1
            % End point is closest.
            C   = B;
        else
            % Intersection point is closest.
            C   = intersectPnt;
        end     

    case 'ray'
        % Ray
        if t0 < 0
            % Start point is closest.
            C   = A;
        else
            % Intersection point is closest.
            C   = intersectPnt;
        end

end

% Distance between independent point and closest point
d   = norm(P-C);

end
```

So if I consider that I have the following figure:

[image]

where the green point is my origin, the blue rays are the rays thrown in the space from origin and red points are the individual points in the space for which I want to measure their distance to each ray the way I am doing it so far is the following:

```
origin = [10 10 0];
rays = [ 0.0420891179448099 -0.246431544552697  0.968245836551854;
         0.310536647204174   0.682690992135673  0.661437827766148;
        -0.746496065726383  -0.0724128707829756 0.661437827766148;
         0.435959418522208  -0.610278121352698 0.661437827766148];
mypts = [4579 4246 1962;
         3961 4670 3277;
         4796 3393  856;
         3277 3787 3529;
          179 3713  160];

for j=1:size(rays,1)
    for i=1:size(mypts,1)
        [D(i,j), C(i,j,:), t0(i,j)] = distancePoint2Line(origin, rays(j,:), mypts(j,:), 'ray');
    end
end
```

However, as I said the above implementation is too slow when the number of rays and individual points increases.

Therefore, I tried to modify the `distancePoint2Line()` function so that I vectorize the processing and pass as arguments the origin point, all the ending points, and all the individual points at once.

```
[d, c, tt0] = distancePoint2LineVec(origin, rays, mypts, 'ray');
```

Below is my modification until getting the intersection points:

```
function [d, C, t0] = distancePoint2LineVec(A, B, P, varargin)
% - lineType definition
if (nargin < 4)
    lineType = 'line';
lineType = 'line';
else
    lineType = varargin{1};
end
%% Algorithm

% Direction vector 
% M = B - A;
% M = bsxfun(@minus, B, A); 
M = B;

% Running parameter t0 defines the intersection point of line through A and B
% and the perpendicular through P
% t0  = dot(M, P - A) / dot(M, M);
K = bsxfun(@minus, P, A);
V = M*K.';
U = M*M.';
t0 = bsxfun(@rdivide, V, diag(U));
t0 = t0(:);

% Intersection point of the perpendicular and line through A and B
% intersectPnt = A + t0 * M;
mul = M.*repmat(t0, [1 size(M,1)]); <---- Getting matrix dimension error here
intersectPnt = bsxfun(@plus,A,mul);

switch lower(lineType)
    case 'line'
        % Line: intersection point is always closest.
        C   = intersectPnt;

    case 'segment'
        % Line segment
        if t0 < 0
            % Start point is closest.
            C   = A;
        elseif t0 > 1
            % End point is closest.
            C   = B;
        else
            % Intersection point is closest.
            C   = intersectPnt;
        end     

    case 'ray'
        % Ray
        if t0 < 0
            % Start point is closest.
            C   = A;
        else
            % Intersection point is closest.
            C   = intersectPnt;
        end

end

% Distance between independent point and closest point
d   = norm(P-C);

end
```

but the point is that I am getting an error there since the dimensions are not matching for the multiplication. I searched it a bit and it seems that there isn't a direct way to do it. Any ideas how to solve it efficiently?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can shorten all this considerably. You basically want the vectorized version of a operation, but it gets a bit obscured with all the sheer amount of information you aded

Comment: Yeah, stripping this back it's "quickest way to calculate shortest point->line distance" then "how best to scale this calculation for multiple points and lines"

Comment: @Ander Biguri trying to be detailed to what I want to achieve, last if you remember need to add more info. It is also a kind of sanity check for the other operations that I am trying to transform in case that someone has a better proposal to the way I am doing it. @ Wolfie I think the function for the simple point -> line distance is already quite fast and accurate, therefore the question is mainly how to scale this for multiple points and lines and for that reason I am showing what I have done already.

Comment: As far as I see, there is no reason to think that doing it in one go would be significantly faster. Have you profiled your code?

Comment: Not really, but for a test case that I can recall of 2000 rays x 1300 points it can take a couple of hours with the `for` loops. I think with vectorization it can be done faster.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a first solution to which I ended and seems quite fast:

```
function [d, C, t0] = distancePoint2LineVec(A, B, P, varargin)
% - lineType definition
if (nargin < 4)
    lineType = 'line';
else
    lineType = varargin{1};
end
%% Algorithm

% find if the origin point is withing the points and initialize it to Inf
[~,indx]=ismember(A,P,'rows');

if indx ~= 0
    P(indx,:) = Inf;
end

% Direction vector 
% M = B - A;
% M = bsxfun(@minus, B, A); 
M = B;

% Running parameter t0 defines the intersection point of line through A and B
% and the perpendicular through P
% t0  = dot(M, P - A) / dot(M, M);
K = bsxfun(@minus, P, A);
V = M*K.';
U = M*M.';
t0 = bsxfun(@rdivide, V, diag(U));
t0 = t0(:);

% Intersection point of the perpendicular and line through A and B
% intersectPnt = A + t0 * M;
mul = bsxfun(@times, repmat(M, [size(P,1) 1]), t0);
intersectPnt = bsxfun(@plus, repmat(A, [size(t0,1) 1]), mul);

C = intersectPnt;

idx = find(t0<0);
idx2 = find(t0>1);
% C(idx,:) = repmat(A,[size(idx,1) 1]);

switch lower(lineType)
    case 'line'
        % Line: intersection point is always closest.
        C   = intersectPnt;

    case 'segment'
        % Line segment
%         if t0 < 0
            % Start point is closest.
%             C   = A;
            C(idx,:) = repmat(A,[size(idx,1) 1]);
%         elseif t0 > 1
            % End point is closest.
%             C   = B;
            C(idx2,:) = repmat(B,[size(idx2,1) 1]);
%         else
            % Intersection point is closest.
%             C   = intersectPnt;
%         end     

    case 'ray'
        % Ray
%         if t0 < 0
            % Start point is closest.
%             C   = A;
%             C   = Inf;
%         else
            % Intersection point is closest.
%             C   = intersectPnt;
%         end
        C(idx,:) = repmat([Inf Inf Inf],[size(idx,1) 1]);

end

% Distance between independent point and closest point
% d   = norm(P-C);
d = pdist2(P,C);
d = d(sub2ind(size(d), repmat((1:size(d,1)).', 1, size(B,1)), (1:size(B,1))+((1:size(B,1):size(d,2))-1).'));


C = permute(reshape(C, size(B,1), size(P,1), []), [2 1 3]);
t0 = reshape(t0, size(B,1), size(P,1))';

end
```

If there are any comments or suggestions for even more improvements I would be glad to hear. Thanks again.